# How to add an admin panel to an existing ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, adminlte

I have created a project which on the client side uses ReactJS and on the server side .NET Core 3.1. I have API controllers, loggers, services, repositories etc.

Now I would like to add an Admin panel. I decided to add another .NET Core 3.1 project only for the admin panel and would like to use the same database and identity to control users.

The problem is that I'm not able to sign into the DB that is in use in first project... and I don't know really how to achieve that.

Or maybe I should add AdminLTE to main project - but how?

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was in my custom login page...in first project I decided to have login and password as a way to log in user. 
In custom login there is an **email** instead of login to log in user.
And that is it.